# Find the general solution of $(t-1)y''-ty'+y=2e^t$ knowing that $e^t$ is a solution of $(t-1)y''-ty'+y=0.$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the general solution of $(t-1)y''-ty'+y=2e^t$ knowing that $e^t$ is a solution of $(t-1)y''-ty'+y=0$.

First thing I did is see that $t$ is also a solution of $(t-1)y''-ty'+y=0$ so I could solve the problem obtaining the Green function, but when I wrote the integral and tried to solve it I saw that it was really hard, and checked it online and saw that it can't be done with fundamental functions.

How can I proced to get the general solution now?

Comment: An arguably brute force approach would be to use Frobenius' method directly.

Comment: The solution is given by $$\left\{\left\{y(t)\to c_1 e^t-c_2 t+2 \left(-e t
   \text{Ei}(t-1)+e^t+e^t \log
   (t-1)\right)\right\}\right\}$$

Comment: This is not so nice!

Comment: The integral is hard to evaluate whatver the method used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use reduction of order to get a second independent solution to the
homogeneous equation $(t - 1)y'' -ty' + y = 0$, namely $y(t) = t$, and then use variation of parameters to get the general solution to the inhomogeneous equation $(t - 1)y'' -ty' + y = 2e^t$. It will be of the form $v_1(t)e^t + v_2(t)t + Ae^t + Bt$ for appropriately defined functions $v_1(t)$ and $v_2(t)$, where $A$ and $B$ are arbitrary constants.

Answer (score 0):

$$(t-1)y''-ty'+y=2e^t$$
Substitute:
$$y=ve^t,y'=e^t(v'+v), y''=e^t(v''+2v'+v)$$
$$(t-1)v''+v'(t-2)=2$$
You can reduce the order now. Not sure that the integral will be easier to evaluate.

Comment: This integral can't be evaluated with elementary functions. Frobenius serie won't help that much